# Open terminal in XFCE from script and activate python virtualenv

Tags: python3, virtualenv, xfce4-terminal

I try to open a new terminal window in XFCE and activate python3 virtualenv in there using the following line in a bash script:

```
xfce4-terminal --working-directory=$HOME/path/to/project --maximize \
-e 'bash -c "source $HOME/path/to/project/venv/bin/activate; bash"'
```

The strange thing is that the virtualenv gets kind of activated since:

```
which python
```

shows the correct path to the virtualenv directory and the project seems to be working fine.

However I don't see the `(venv)` to the left from the shell prompt. Moreover, when I enter `deactivate` it complains that no such command can be found.

Is there a proper way to solve this problem?